# python equivalent of R's range

Tags: python, r

Is there a python equivalent of R's range?

A builtin function that returns max and min of a list (or series or similar)?

```
> range(1:3)
[1]  1 3
```

I could do something like `min([1, 2, 3)` and `max([1, 2, 3])` but wondering if there's something that combines both.

Comment: `def rang(l): return min(l), max(l)` - here, something that combines both.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a builtin function in python that is the equivalent of `range` in R. However, it is easy enough to create using base python.

```
def range_r(lst):
    min_ = min(lst)
    max_ = max(lst)
    return min_, max_

range_r(range(1, 20)) # returns (1, 19)
range_r([1, 3, 5, 10]) # returns (1, 10)
```